# Когда нужно использовать CoInitialize?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, когда нужно использовать связку CoInitialize(nil); - CoUninitialize;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В любом Thread, в котором планируется использовать COM объекты все места использования следует обложить CoInitialize(nil); - CoUninitialize.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, вот эта статья вам поможет - [Понимание потоковых моделей в COM при программировании на Delphi](http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/delphi/delphi-thread-model.html), в частности на [стр. 5](http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/delphi/delphi-thread-model-page5.html)